# Simple autohotkey v2.0 script not working in Chrome

Tags: autohotkey

I am using the following script in Autohotkey v2.0. I want to hold ctrl + alt and then type "s" for "Small (S)" to populate and ctrl + alt + "ss" and have "Extra Small (XS)" populate. I want to use this in chrome. But it's not working even when run as admin. I want it to override any chrome shortcut keys that may conflict whenever I'm on the website google.com only (in any tab) - ie type it in the search bar or any text field when on the domain google.com.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe AND WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") AND WinActive("Google - Google Chrome")
#Hotstring *C??
:*C0:^!s::Send, Small (S)
:*C0:^!ss::Send, Extra Small (XS)
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example for for HotKey F1 to Mute when Chrome is active, please try:

```
#Hotif WinActive("ahk_class chrome.exe") or WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
{
    F1::Send "{Volume_Mute}"
}
```

PS: There are so many Changes from v1.1 to v2.0, please go through [enter link description here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/v2-changes.htm)